# Why the connection is timing out with Elastic IP but not with the public DNS

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I've setup a Redis Server on AWS. The Redis server has its own security group: `sg-redis`.
I also have a webserver under another security group (`sg-webserver`) which is suppose to be able to connect to the redis server.
For this security group I've opened:

- TCP 6379 for sg-webserver
- TCP 22 for sg-webserver

My redis server has an Elastic IP associated with the EC2 instance.

From the webserver, if I telnet my redis server using the Elastic IP I get a connection timeout:

```
[root@web-server:~]# telnet 54.11.22.333 6379
Trying 54.11.22.333...
telnet: connect to address 54.11.22.333: Connection timed out
```

Now I do the same using the Public DNS of the Redis server:

```
[root@web-server:~]# telnet ec2-11-22-33-444.compute-1.amazonaws.com 6379
Trying 10.22.33.444...
Connected to ec2-11-22-33-444.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I can see that the webserver is translating the public DNS to the AWS internal IP (not the Elastic IP) so I guess this is why it's working.

Now my question is why this is not working with the Elastic IP ?
Do I have to use the Public DNS internally?

Cheers, Maxime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use public DNS internally. For that reason alone, it will resolve to the internal or external ip depending where you use it.

Comment: Also worth noting is that data transfer to or from "Amazon EC2, Amazon RDS and Amazon ElastiCache instances or Elastic Network Interfaces in the same Availability Zone" using a "public or elastic IP" is not free, and incurs a $0.01/GB data transfer charge on each side of the connection, while using a private IP is $0.00. http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Comment: but with an elastic IP it's very easy to have a backup redis instance and switch to that by switching the EIP. you've chosen to set the private IP in your config files and change it if the redis machine IP changes?